# Only present number with precision if needed - is it possible?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, printf, precision, nslog

Is there a possibility to present the same variable in different precisions?
For example, if I'm presenting an addition of two integers, it would be like:

```
result = 2+3;
NSLog(@"%.0f", result);
```

but with a division it would be like:

```
result = 2/3;
NSLog(@"%.1f", result);
```

Although presenting the π (pi) it would be like:

```
result = M_PI;
NSLog(@"%.19f", result); //And it would be 3.141592653589793238
```

Comment: How do you intend to distinguish among those in your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSNumber` will do some quick-and-dirty formatting for you,

```
NSNumber * five = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:3+2];
NSNumber * twoThirds = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:2/3.0];
NSNumber * mPi = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:M_PI];

NSLog(@"%@", [five stringValue]);
NSLog(@"%@", [twoThirds stringValue]);
NSLog(@"%@", [mPi stringValue]);
```

> 2011-11-17 21:52:12.621 Precision[13359:903] 5
>   2011-11-17 21:52:12.624 Precision[13359:903] 0.6666666666666666
>   2011-11-17 21:52:12.625 Precision[13359:903] 3.141592653589793

but you should really use an `NSNumberFormatter`:

```
NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setUsesSignificantDigits:YES];

NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:five]);
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:twoThirds]);

[formatter setMaximumSignificantDigits:16];
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:mPi]);
```

> 2011-11-17 21:52:12.629 Precision[13359:903] 5
>   2011-11-17 21:52:12.630 Precision[13359:903] 0.666667
>   2011-11-17 21:52:12.630 Precision[13359:903] 3.14159265358979

The [string format specifiers](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html) also allow variable precision; use an asterisk instead of a digit after the decimal point:

```
int precision = 3;
NSLog(@"%.*f", precision, 2/3.0);
```